# Flutter - "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

Tags: ios, flutter, url, safari

I am trying to open the telegram URL and it's content but I am getting this error message - "safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

URL I am trying to access: https://t.me/CoinDCX_Go_Announcements
When I click VIEW IN TELEGRAM, I am getting a popup with the above error message. What could be the issue with this url ?

I am using the url launcher plugin to launch this url.

[image]

This is the URL launcher code. But seems like this is telegram share link issue.

```
static launchUrl({String url, BuildContext context}) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url,);
    } else {
     print('there is some issue');
    }
  }
```

Comment: post the code to show how you implemented `launchUrl`

Comment: @DarShan I have added the launchUrl code. But seems like this is more of the telegram share like issue.

Comment: @vikaspandey I have the same case like yours when opening apps in appstore. did you find any solution ?